# Optimizar extracción de datos en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo una tabla con proveedores la cual contiene aproximadamente 4 mil proveedores y de cada proveedor saco información de otra tabla que tiene millones de registros lo que hace que la consulta se vuelva muy lenta porque tambien consulto los datos entre ciertas fechas en específico, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$fechaIni = $this->input->post('fechaI');
        $fechaFin = $this->input->post('fechaF');
        $proveedores = Provider::get();
        $cont=0;
        $indicators = array();

        foreach ($proveedores as $key => $value) {
            $visit = DB::table('indicators')
                                ->where('provider_id', $value['id_proveedor'])
                                ->where('type', 'visit')
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fechaIni)
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $fechaFin)
                                ->count();
            $phone = DB::table('indicators')
                                ->where('provider_id', $value['id_proveedor'])
                                ->where('type', 'phone')
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fechaIni)
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $fechaFin)
                                ->count();
            $mensajes = DB::table('indicators')
                                ->where('provider_id', $value['id_proveedor'])
                                ->where('type', 'contact_request')
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fechaIni)
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $fechaFin)
                                ->count();
            $login = DB::table('indicators')
                                ->where('provider_id', $value['id_proveedor'])
                                ->where('type', 'login')
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fechaIni)
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $fechaFin)
                                ->count();
            if($visit>0 || $phone>0 || $mensajes>0 || $login>0) {
                $indicators[$cont]['nombres'] = $value['nombre'];
                $indicators[$cont]['visit'] = $visit;
                $indicators[$cont]['phone'] = $phone;
                $indicators[$cont]['mensajes'] = $mensajes;
                $indicators[$cont]['login'] = $login;
                $cont+=1;
            }
        }
```

Como podrán notar de la tabla indicators necesito sacar 4 datos de cada proveedor entre ciertas fechas por lo que recorre 4 veces esa tabla que tiene 1 millón de registros por cada proveedor.

¿Saben alguna manera de optimizar eso?

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es con groupBy(), tal vez la más común, usando el campo del cual se desea contar:

```
DB::table('indicators')
          ->groupBy('type')
          ->whereProviderId($value['id_proveedor'])
          ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fechaIni)
          ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $fechaFin)
          ->get(array(
              DB::raw('type'),
              DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')
          ))
          ->toArray();
```

En caso que se desee obtener exclusivamente los 4 conteos de los tipos mostrados en la pregunta, habría que hacer un filtro adicional.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero si se tiene que hacer un conteo exclusivo por cada type ya que posteriormente eso se mostrará en una tabla.

Comment: Pues eso lo está haciendo como tal.

Comment: ¿Y contaría todos los type de manera individual? me retornaría un array con los datos contados, ejemplo: Phone=4, Visit=7, Mensajes=3, Login=9

Comment: Por favor pruebe el código primero.

Comment: De acuerdo voy a hacer pruebas con eso